# Sorting out C++ inheritance access protection puzzle

Tags: c++

I've got kind of a puzzle I am trying to sort out, without necessarily exposing key parts publicly.

```
template<class Feature>
struct Fixture {
private:

  Feature f;

protected:
  Fixture() : f() {}

public:

  Feature* const get() { return &f; }
};

struct MyFeature {
protected:
  MyFeature() {}
};

struct FixtureHost : public Fixture<MyFeature> {
};
```

At least using the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 compiler, I am getting errors along the lines of C2248, 'MyFeature::MyFeature': cannot access protected member declared in class 'MyFeature'.

I want for access to the Feature as well as the Fixture access to be protected. Really, only FixtureHost, or things within the friendship circle, should be allowed to instantiate either of them.

But it seems like this is too much for the little old C++ compiler? If I have to expose the constructor(s) publicly, so be it, but I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: [friend](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend)?

Comment: `friend Fixture<MyFeature>;`

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: That was intentional. Yes, in my code, friendships are declared. However, the error stands. Now, I've declared friends of an early declared class, but I don't think it necessarily needs to know the full type. But I could be wrong about that. Still the error is strange since in now way should the host, nor the Fixture, inherit from the Feature.

Comment: As far as I can figure it to be, here's my MCVE: http://rextester.com/CIWBD27276 / of course, "compiling" isn't the case. This is just an MVE, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: The code in your question should be the MCVE. In other words, if someone copy and pastes exactly the code from your question, they should get the same compiler output that you get.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of `MyFeature` is protected, however `Fixture<MyFeature>` tries to access it by the code `f()`.   `protected` means that only the current class or classes deriving from it can access the name, but `Fixture<MyFeature>` is not derived from `MyFeature`.

You could have `MyFeature` add the line to the class definition:

```
friend class Fixture<MyFeature>;
```

or consider a different design, such as making `Fixture<T>` derive from `T`.

Comment: Yea, no, Fixture should in no way derive from T. It really should be that T informs the member of Fixture.

Comment: And to be clear, yes, I've forward declared the templates and classes and such, for that to be the case, but the compiler still chokes.

Comment: Your comments are unclear to me. The `friend` declaration I suggested fixes your problem (as shown in your MCVE which now compiles with no errors), are you saying you still have a problem of some sort?

Comment: Not according to this example: http://rextester.com/RJQGM97017, which the error just makes no sense. The compiler has lost its brain. source_file.cpp(18): error C2248: 'MyFeature::MyFeature': cannot access protected member declared in class 'MyFeature'

Comment: Ok, well, in this contrived example, it works. How strange. http://rextester.com/EQY45553

Comment: @mwpowellhtxCopy and paste the line out of my answer and into line 30 of [your original MCVE](http://rextester.com/CIWBD27276). Also you don't need the redundant friend declarations on lines 16 and 17 of that program (which do not even appear in your question). You seem to have tried everything except my actual suggestion